# Accessing external variables from within a Jinja2 macro

Tags: macros, jinja2

I have the following Jinja2 files but the macro `do_stuff` doesn't appear to be able to access the values of `something` and `something_else` that are defined in `my_template.jinja2`.

Is there a way to make this possible? I'm aware I can pass them in manually to the macro, but as their values stay the same for every invocation of the macro in a template file, it would be nice not to have to do that.

If I embed the macro directly in `my_template.jinja2` it works but then it would have to be duplicated across all templates that use it.

**macro.jinja2**

```
{% macro do_stuff(value) %}
     <p>Something is {{ something | default('nothing') }}.</p>
     <p>Something else is {{ something_else | default ('nothing') }}.</p>
     <p>Values is {{ value }}.</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

**base_template.jinja2**

```
{% from 'macros.jinja2' import do_stuff %}
{# Other common stuff goes here #}
```

**my_template.jinja2**

```
{% extends 'base_template.jinja2' %}

{% set something = "foo" %}
{% set something_else = "bar" %}

{# Content #}
{{ do_stuff("baz1") }}
{# More content #}
{{ do_stuff("baz2") }}
{# More content #}
{# etc. #}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this and ended up just passing in default arguments every time:

**macro.jinja2**

```
{% macro do_stuff(something, something_else, value) %}
    <p>Something is {{ something | default('nothing') }}.</p>
    <p>Something else is {{ something_else | default ('nothing') }}.</p>
    <p>Values is {{ value }}.</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

**my_template.jinja2**

```
{% extends 'base_template.jinja2' %}

{% set something = "foo" %}
{% set something_else = "bar" %}

{# Content #}
{{ do_stuff(something, something_else, "baz1") }}
{# More content #}
{{ do_stuff(something, something_else, "baz2") }}
{# More content #}
{# etc. #}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `with context` in the import

`{% from 'macros.jinja2' import do_stuff with context%}`

See [Access Macro Context in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517615/access-macro-context-in-jinja2)